# Siblimg import with dependencies

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import a sibling module that itself has imports from another module.

The tree is as follows

```
├── USA
├── NewYork
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Manhattan.py
│   └── Queens.py
├── Atlanta
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Buckhead.py
```

The code is as follows

```
#Queens.py
def myFunction():
  print("I am in Queens")
```

```
#Manhattan.py
from Queens import myFunction
class Manhattan():

  def __init__(self):
    myFunction()
    print("I am in Manhattan")
```

Now, I want to instantiate an object of class Manhattan in Buckhead

```
#Buckhead.py
from NewYork.Manhattan import Manhattan

man = Manhattan()
```

I am getting a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queens'
```

How do I go about instantiating the Manhttan class that ITSELF imports a function from the Queen module?

Comment: I am surprised that your importing of `NewYork.Manhattan` file actually worked, because when I tried, it didn't work, presumably because `NewYork` is not in the same directory as `Buckhead.py`. Are you sure of the tree?

Comment: Yup! Definitely works on my end. It looks like sibling imports work without have to worry about relative imports. Not sure if that’s a new Python feature. I’m on 3.6.